# Eclipse JDT Refactor method programatically fails in subclass

Tags: java, refactoring, eclipse-jdt, automated-refactoring

I am using `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod` and calling `method.rename(newName, true, new NullProgressMonitor());` on an interface.

It refactors interface method, but fails to refactor its implementation classes-methods.

For example:

```
interface Animal {
    void eat(); // refactors here
}

class Dog implements Animal {

    // fails to refactor this
    void eat() {
    }
}
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct.

The code should look for implementations of this method (through the [Java Search Engine API](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_search.htm)) and accordingly rename the overriding methods as part of that same refactoring.

Comment: Thanks. But no :( However found an alternate ( see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gosu!

But this works for me!

```
RenameMethodProcessor processor = new RenameVirtualMethodProcessor(method);
        processor.setNewElementName(newName);
        processor.setUpdateReferences(true);

        RenameRefactoring refactoring = new RenameRefactoring(processor);


        refactoring.checkAllConditions(new NullProgressMonitor());
        Change res = refactoring.createChange(new NullProgressMonitor());

        res.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
```